# Meaning of centred and uncentered r square

Tags: regression, 2sls

I'm not sure I understand fully the meaning of centred/uncentered r2.
Is uncentered r2 is same as adjusted r2? and if not, how can I know the adjusted r2?

That result estimated by IV analysis.

[the results are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW6BR.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW6BR.png)